# Bash: case-esac construction in runtime

Tags: bash

I need to generate keys for the operator 'case..esac' during the execution of the script, having an array of pairs:

```
map=(
   "key1:expr1"
   "key2:expr2"
   "key3:expr3"
)
```

Where left is key, and right is expression.
Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: And the question is....

Comment: eval should do: `help eval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of cause you can generate the bash code into a string and eval it with `eval`, but standard way of implementing the behavior you want in bash is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#statements, can read them from the file, etc.
key1='echo "hello 1"'
key2='echo "hello 2"'
key3='echo "hello 3"'

userinput="key3"

# print
echo ${!userinput}

# and likewise eval:
eval ${!userinput}
```